# How can I set the publisher on a PubSub node using Smack?

Tags: xmpp, publish-subscribe, smack

i'm developing a chat with Smack libraries and Openfire server. I would like to set a user to publisher on my pubsub node.
I've searched for the web but i can't find anything.

I've set the pubsub with this configuration:

```
nodeconfig.setPublishModel(PublishModel.publishers);
```

I've saw that i can create the affiliation:

```
Affiliation af = new Affiliation(mypubsub,Affiliation.Type.publisher);
```

What can i do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to retrieve the Node's `ConfigurationForm` via `Node.getNodeConfiguration()`, create an answer form from it with `createAnswerForm`, and call `Form.setAnswer(String, String)` to set the `pubsub#publisher` option. Then send the answer form with `Node.sendConfigurationForm(Form)`.

```
from.setAnswer("pubsub#publisher", "publisher@example.org");
```

See also [XEP-60 8.2](http://www.xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0060.html#owner-configure).

Comment: What if i would like to remove the publisher?

Comment: The configuration form's `pubsub#publisher` field is of type `jid-multi` and contains not the delta, but the publisher list "to set" on the node. So if you want to remove a publisher you send the field with the list of publishers minus the publisher you want to remove.